# Summation notation for the sum of roots of a polynomial N at a time

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers

I've been studying Vieta's formula and would like a to find the general Sigma notation for the sum of roots 2 at a time.

For example consider the the polynomial:

$$
  ( z - \alpha_1)( z - \alpha_2)( z - \alpha_3)( z - \alpha_4) = 0
$$

The roots are: $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3$ and $\alpha_4$.

The sum of the roots, taken 2 at a time is:
$$
   \alpha_1 \alpha_2 + \alpha_1 \alpha_3 + \alpha_1  \alpha_4 + \alpha_2 \alpha_3 + \alpha_2 \alpha_4 + \alpha_3\alpha_4
$$

I would like to express this in Sigma notation.  I presume a

$$
   \sum \sum \alpha_i\alpha_j
$$

is used but can't figure out the Sigma terminals.  Then extend this to $n$ roots.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial

Comment: I was going to write an answer with a bunch of less than signs, but it's the very first equation in the page @MartinR linked. Go with that.

Answer (score 2):

How about

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} \alpha_i \alpha_j.$$

Edit:  One way to wrestle with these things is to plot the subscripts as points.  In your example, you'd have

$$(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4).$$

If you plot those points, you get a nice triangle.  Then set up the limits of summation the way you would a double integral.

Comment: Thank-you so much for that information.  Neat!

Answer (score 2):

$$
\alpha_1 \alpha_2 + \alpha_1 \alpha_3 + \alpha_1  \alpha_4 + \alpha_2 \alpha_3 + \alpha_2 \alpha_4 + \alpha_3\alpha_4
$$
is the second [elementary symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) $e_2(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \alpha_4)$. It can be expressed as
$$
e_2(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \alpha_4) = \sum_{1 \le i < j \le 4} \alpha_i \alpha_j \, .
$$
This notation easily extends to $n$ roots:
$$
e_2(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n) = \sum_{1 \le i < j \le n} \alpha_i \alpha_j 
$$
and to products of higher degree:
$$
e_3(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n) = \sum_{1 \le i < j < k\le n} \alpha_i \alpha_j \alpha_k 
$$
and generally
$$
e_k(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n) = \sum_{1 \le i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k\le n} \prod_{j=1}^k  \alpha_{i_j}\, .
$$

Answer (score 1):

There is a specific sum notation for this kind of summation. The *[symmetric sum](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Symmetric_sum)* notation $\sum_{\color{blue}{\mathrm{sym}}}$ is the sum over all permutations of the elements of a predefined set $S$. If we sum over a subset $T\subseteq S$ only, then this notation is used to sum over all $\binom{|S|}{|T|}$ subsets of size $|T|$ in $|S|$.

> If $S=\{\alpha_1, \alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4\}$, then
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{\mathrm{sym}}\alpha_1\alpha_2}&
> \color{blue}{=\alpha_1\alpha_2+\alpha_1\alpha_3+\alpha_1\alpha_4+\alpha_2\alpha_3+\alpha_2\alpha_4+\alpha_3\alpha_4}\\
> &=\sum_{1\leq i< j\leq 4}\alpha_i\alpha_j
> \end{align*}

*Hint:* Another specific sum notation used in a different context ist the *[cyclic sum](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Cyclic_sum)* notation $\sum_{\color{blue}{\mathrm{cyc}}}$, which is the sum over elements of a predefined set $S$ in a cyclic manner $\alpha_1\to \alpha_2\to \alpha_3\to \alpha_4\to \alpha_1$.

Comment: Very useful Markus.  Thank-you.

Comment: @Stephan: You're welcome. :-)